# Using Date instead of Timestamp

Tags: java, date

My code:

```
    Calendar calendar = DateProvider.getCalendarInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1970);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    date = calendar.getTime();
    Timestamp epochTimeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

I want to eliminate the use of time stamp in this situation, how can achieve the same thing here with epochTimeStamp without using java.sql.Timestamp? I need the format to be same as if I was using Timestamp.

Comment: If you're talking about format to write a `String` representation of the date, you should use `SimpleDateFormat` instead.

Comment: What are you doing with the Timestamp?

Comment: We don't know what you mean when you say you "need the format to be the same". Can you please clarify?

Comment: Timestamp gives me: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.007
Date will give Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970
I have to use the Timestamp i get back later in the code to check if it falls under a certain range of times.

Comment: Then you were talking about a String representation of the date...

Comment: Is there a way to get ride of day of week, Thu part?

Comment: You can format a `Date` any way you like using `SimpleDateFormat`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a `String` representation of your `Date`, then use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert the `Date` object into a `String`:

```
Calendar calendar = ...
//...
date = calendar.getTime();
Timestamp epochTimeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
try {
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(epochTimeStamp));
} catch (Exception e) {
    //handle it!
}
```

From your example, prints

```
01/01/1970 09:21:18
01/01/1970 09:21:18
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the epoch time in the same format as `TimeStamp`:

```
public class FormatDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss:SSS");
        LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(datetime.format(format));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to represent date time objects in Java is to use the Joda Time libraries.

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
...

 LocalDate startDate= new LocalDate();//"2014-05-06T10:59:45.618-06:00");
 //or DateTime startDate = new DateTime ();// creates instance of current time 

 String formatted = 
    startDate.toDateTimeAtCurrentTime().toString("MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss");
```

There are several ways to do formatting, setting and getting Time using these libraries that has been more reliable than using the JDK Date and Calendar libraries.  These will persist in hibernate/JPA as well. If nothing else, this hopefully gives you options.